# Settings.bundle limitations

Tags: iphone, ipad, passwords, settings, settings.bundle

I've got an app that requires a password, which is set within the app itself. However, once a password has been set, if the user forgets the password and needs to reset it, I thought we could reset the password in Settings.bundle and hoped that the device would prompt for a password in order to make such a change.

The goal is so that only the owner of the device will be able to reset their password. If someone else resets the password they'll be stuck without ability to access the app.

I've researched and found that buttons (like Safari's "Clear History" and "Clear Cache") cannot be used by 3rd party developers.

I've created a Toggle Switch in Settings.bundle that starts at "Off" and is labeled "Reset Password." When users toggle this on and return to the app, it prompts them to set up a new password.

However - I can't find a way to programmatically change the toggle in preferences back to "Off" at this point so the user isn't prompted to set up a new password every time they open the app from that point on unless they go back to settings and turn the toggle off.

I'm starting to think that this isn't possible at all. Does anybody know more that can chime in?

Second part of the question is whether there is a way to require users to enter their device password in order to make a change? If there is a way to prompt for the device password I will be able to use that as the security measure to allow them to reset their password.

Thank you all so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the "device password" are you referring to the passcode used to unlock a device?

Comment: I was thinking it would be the "Apple ID Password" that is required for downloading apps...

Comment: Using the Apple ID password as protection would make no difference. Someone else could change the Apple ID associated with the device, and then open your app and change the password. There is no protection on the sign out button.

Answer (score 1):

The data stored in the app's settings is available through NSUserDefaults. You can get the state of a ToggleSwitch using the `boolForKey:` method passing the switch's Identifier as parameter. You can also set its state using the `setBool:forKey` method.